# How can I use django and xcode to make an iphone app with login support?

Tags: iphone, django, xcode

I have a django app that I made and have implemented a plist into it so that xcode can get the latest info from the database. I used a line of code like this:

```
items = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.186:8000/organizer/1.plist"]];
```

I know I will have to edit this a little bit once I deploy it. How would I make xcode login with a user's credentials so I know that the user is authenticated? Would I have to include the user's credentials in the url or is there some special post thing that i can do to send the credentials securely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restufl API's are supposed to be stateless, so you wouldn't want use a cookie to authenticate a user.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

There are many ways to authenticate users for apis.  You can roll your own or use popular django apps like `piston` or `tastypie` these support a number of authentication schemes.  Including a basic username and password.

You would probably want to make sure you use ssl if a users login and password are being passed in each request.